# Epistemology of derealization

Tags: epistemology, reality, perception

I'm wondering if anyone has analyzed [derealization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derealization) from an epistemological perspective. If one person perceives the world as real and another perceives it as unreal, are we justified in viewing the former as correct/veridical and the latter as pathological? Is it possible that the world is, in fact, "unreal"? Does "unreal" even make sense as a property?

Comment: I think similar phenomenon have been treated within the context of mysticism. Particularly, this sounds like something Buddhist philosophy would be adept at doing especially in its 20th century interactions with phenomenology.

Answer (score 1):

We view derealisation and depersonalisation as pathological because it causes psychological distress.

In this context, 'unreal' is just a word which happens to be used to describe the quality of the conscious experience of the sufferer, and it doesn't have much epistemological considerations (but rather, phenomenogical), IMO. For instance, many other adjectives could be used instead, such as 'dull', 'foggy', etc... (I am afflicted by derealisation).

Diminished visual-limbic connectivity has been observed in the brains of people with derealisation/depersonalisation, which is regarded as a marker that the subjective experience of those individuals is less 'emotionally colored'. Here's a reference: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1737835/ (full text link at the end)

If anything it tells you that even notions that we take for granted such as things being 'real' or you being yourself are fragile enough. It reinforces the idea of numenum vs. phenomenon IMO